# How to view Cassandra number of read/write per seconds

Tags: cassandra, grafana, stargate-oss, k8ssandra

Previously, I deployed Cassandra with `k8ssandra-operator` 1.4 with `kube-prometheus-stack` enabled, inserting data directly to C* node via CQL. I can see `k8ssandra:read/write` rates when access Grafana dashboard on Web UI.

But after enabling `stargate`, and inserting to stargate service, I can't see those metrics. I assumed the way Stargate work is to write/flush temporary SSTables so `k8ssandra:read/write` metrics are not logged.

[image]

Is there any way to see those metrics, `nodetool`? `prometheus`?

**Solutions**

I added these config follow @Arron answer and it worked, have to restart stargate and related prometheus pods.

```
stargate:
  enabled: true
  replicas: 3
  heapMB: 1024
  cpuReqMillicores: 1000
  cpuLimMillicores: 1000
  telemetry:
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Talked to the K8ssandra team on this one.  Try enabling Prometheus telemetry for Stargate:

https://docs.k8ssandra.io/reference/crd/releases/k8ssandra-operator-releases/k8ssandra-operator-crds-1.4/#stargatespectelemetryprometheus

Stargate.spec.telemetry.prometheus
↩ Parent

```
Name    Type    Description    
enabled boolean Enable the creation of Prometheus serviceMonitors for this resource (Cassandra or Stargate).
```

This should allow those metrics to come through.